# Django: Order_by combined two columns

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have following query; There are two columns (dateEmploymentRD and dateTerminationRD).

```
qsPersonnel = qsPersonnel.filter(Q(dateEmploymentRD__isnull=False), 
                                        Q(dateEmploymentRD__lte=personnelDateMax), 
                                        Q(dateTerminationRD__gte=personnelDateMin) | Q(dateTerminationRD__isnull=True), 
                                        Q(dateTerminationRD__lte=personnelDateMax) | Q(dateTerminationRD__isnull=True)).order_by('dateEmploymentRD','dateTerminationRD')
```

I would like to sort that queryset with combined two coulmns (dateEmploymentRD and dateTerminationRD).

But my query is ordering firstly 'dateEmployementRD' and than ordering by 'dateTerminationRD' as below.

How can I order my query by combined two columns?

**Edit-1:** Added views.py

```
def index(request):
    qsPersonnel = filterPersonnel(request)
    qsPersonelgraduatelevel= qsPersonnel.values('graduateLevel',).annotate(Count('graduateLevel')).order_by()
    qsPersoneltask = qsPersonnel.values('task',).annotate(Count('task')).order_by()
    qsPersonelgender = qsPersonnel.values('gender',).annotate(Count('gender')).order_by()
    
    personnelDateMin = request.GET.get('personnelDateMin')
    personnelDateMax = request.GET.get('personnelDateMax')
    personnelDateMaxMin = dtt.strptime(personnelDateMin,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
    personnelDateMaxDate = dtt.strptime(personnelDateMax,'%Y-%m-%d').date()

    qsPersonnelsum = filterPersonnelsum(request)
    
    personnelChart = {}
    qsPersonnelsumbase = filterPersonnelsum(request).aggregate(Count('id'))
    b = qsPersonnelsumbase['id__count']

    personnelChart[personnelDateMin] = b
    


    for i in qsPersonnel:
        if i.dateTerminationRD and i.dateTerminationRD < personnelDateMaxDate:
            b -= 1
            personnelChart[str(i.dateTerminationRD)] = b
            
        elif i.dateEmploymentRD and i.dateEmploymentRD > personnelDateMaxMin:
            b += 1
            personnelChart[str(i.dateEmploymentRD)] = b
    
    personnelChartSorted = dict(sorted(personnelChart.items()))

    context ={
       'qsPersonnel' : qsPersonnel,
       'qsPersonelgraduatelevel' : qsPersonelgraduatelevel,
       'qsPersoneltask' : qsPersoneltask,
       'qsPersonelgender' : qsPersonelgender,
    
    }
    
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combined"? Do you want to sort by the difference between the two or the sum of them?

Comment: I mean: I have two coumn and I would like to order whichever of the two coulmns is earliest, come first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To order by the earliest of two columns you have to add an annotation that calculates the earliest of the two using [`Least`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Least), then you can order by the annotation

```
import datetime
from django.db.models.functions import Least, Coalesce

qsPersonnel = qsPersonnel.annotate(
    earliest=Coalesce(
        Least('dateEmployementRD', 'dateTerminationRD'),
        datetime.datetime.max
    )
).order_by('earliest')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working but beacues of null rows, it is not completely fine. Please find attached picture. first 3 row is not ordering 'earliest. Even I tried `Greatest`. [link](https://ibb.co/3NrpDSH)

Comment: @Seckinyilmaz which DB are you using? The docs do mention the inconsistent behaviour between DBs for this

Comment: @Seckinyilmaz Using `Coalesce` you should be able to get the right behaviour. Updated the answer

Comment: Unfortunately ordered not fine. Null date areas is not ordered old to new :( [link](https://ibb.co/bgNQJgm)

Comment: Can you add your model? Looks like the results are being ordered like strings??

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Actually you are right. according to my model there are strings. I am trying to create a chart that have x axis is date (changed total personel number date) and y axis is total personel number. I tought if I use for loop and If condition I can handle it. But I suppose I should find another method.